# Press one button fires several

Tags: android

I have 15 buttons with deferent id:

```
 <Button
         android:id="@+id/button14"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="140dp"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="955dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
         android:onClick="myClickHandler"
         android:text="test"
         android:textSize="@dimen/NomenklaturaNameLong" 
           android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
```

One eventhadler for all:

```
public void myClickHandler(View target)
    {
        Intent intent1;
        switch (target.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1:
                ButtonOn (Asortiment.SmenaButName[0],Asortiment.SmenaButPrice[0]);
            break;
            case R.id.button10:
                ButtonOn (Asortiment.SmenaButName[9],Asortiment.SmenaButPrice[9]);
            break;
            case R.id.button11:
                ButtonOn (Asortiment.SmenaButName[10],Asortiment.SmenaButPrice[10]);
            break;
.................
```

When I push the button, two string adding to list view row. Sometime I push one button, but see that added several different strings, like if I press several buttons in one moment.
What can it be?

Comment: You don't miss a `break;` somewhere? (Made that mistake once)

Comment: No, I don't. It is happen occasionally

Comment: You don't add an eventlistener in the Java code also?

Comment: Are all the buttons at the same physical X/Y location?

Comment: No, I don't, all the buttons have different location

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, but to debug:
Add at every button a `System.out.println("button #");` so:

```
case R.id.button1:
   ButtonOn (Asortiment.SmenaButName[0],Asortiment.SmenaButPrice[0]);
   System.out.println("button 1");
break;

case R.id.button2:
   ButtonOn (Asortiment.SmenaButName[1],Asortiment.SmenaButPrice[1]);
   System.out.println("button 2");
break;
```

And so on.
Then use your buttons, and look if their is a pattern.
Maybe you can find out where it goes wrong?